# preg_match pattern with signal character

Tags: php, regex

I need a pattern which is able to find a word wrapped in two signal characters.
Basically something like

```
$string = "bablabla __test__ blablabla"
preg_match("/__\w__/", $string, $result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Here is a nice regex cheat sheet. Write your own expression, then get back at me if you have a problem. http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: `\w` just finds a single alphanumeric character. Read up on repetetion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` is a single word character.  It would match `__t__` but not multiple characters like `__test__`.  Try `\w+`